# Pycharm typehints for __getitem__

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have problem with typehints in Pycharm and i don't know, if something like this is possible.

I need from Pycharm to typehint keys from dictionary, but not from standard dict object, but from custom class with defined **getitem** function.

Like this, everything work perfect

[image: Correct typehints]

But when i want to do this

[image]

There is problem.

Is there any possibility to achieve typehint like this? Or only possibility is write own plugin for Pycharm.

Comment: Please post code as code, and only the absolutely necessary parts as screenshots.

Comment: I don't think so, at least not without plugins.

Comment: And do you know some plugin that work like this? Or I must create new plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It's special support for `dict` literals, keys are captured and suggested in completion.

Type hinting is not able to help here because it is about types, not particular `dict` keys or values.